# present continuous with from vs present perfect continuous with since

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, present-continuous

Is this the right sentence grammatically?

> People are still using this Gist from 2013.

I think **‘People have been using this gist since 2013’** should be right.

But I am not sure, Maybe the above one is used in some other situation about which I don't know.

Can anyone explain it?

I found this sentence on this GitHub gist link [here](https://gist.github.com/TylerFisher/6127328).

Comment: It's just fast writing for: People are still using this Gist. It's  from 2013. People are not always careful with ambiguities on that type of site.  Using a Gist from 2013 can mean the Gist dates to 2013.

Comment: What @Lambie said. The point being made isn't that people have been *using* it since 2013 (although that's quite probably true). It's that ***the thing they have been using*** (from some unspecified point in past time up until *now*) "comes from / dates from / was created in" 2013.

Answer (score 1):

**for** and **since** [month, time, year, phrase]+ action verbs

**trigger the present perfect or the present perfect continuous.**

- He has been here since yesterday.
- He has been playing the violin for three hours.
- He has played OR been playing the violin for three years.

Action verbs can be either tense, depending on what you want to say. Stative verbs, on the other hand, take the present prefect.

- This soup has tasted better ever since you changed the recipe.
- They have been nice since you spoke to them.